# Copy paste rows meeting conditions stated from a multiple selection in a drop-down list (with no repetition)

Tags: excel, vba, row, dropdown, copy-paste

I have:

1) one worksheet named "Data" for my products data base;

2) one worksheet named "Quotation ENG" for products quotations based on selected products from the data base;

3) one worksheet named "Manager" with dropdown lists to make the criteria selections.

Then, I have two pieces of code running fine independently.

One named Sub Quote is for copy-pasting part of the rows from my database to the quotation sheet when a criterion is met,

And one named Sub Worksheet_Change (credits: TrumpExcel) is for enabling multiple selections in a dropdown list.

I'm quite clueless on how to change the code of my Sub Quote module to make the copy-paste operation possible if the dropdown lists enable multiple criteria. ANy guidance is welcome :)

[image]

```
Sub Quote()

Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim Company As String
Dim InfoA As String
Dim Finalrow As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
Set Target = Worksheets("Quotation ENG")
Company = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value 'Where one dropdown list is located.
InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E7").Value 'Where one dropdown list is located.

Source.Select
Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To Finalrow
    If Cells(I, 1) = Company And Cells(I, 2) = InfoA Then
    Source.Range(Cells(I, 16), Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
    End If

Next I

Target.Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub

=============================================================

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub

If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Post some sample data. You can edit your question and paste a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not know it was possible to add a picture. I think I tried one year ago or so and because of some reputation points limitation I could not do it at that time. Never checked again since. Let me know if it is still unclear with the picture I added. FYI The red box is here to highlight the issue. Now I have multiple criteria in cell E5, the code in Sub Quote is unable to manage/split it. Maybe by using a LEFT function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored some parts of your code and turned the company variable into an array so it can store several values. Please read the comments inside the code.

As a suggestion, try to use [Excel structured tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) to store your data. It's gonna be easier to work with them in the future.

Replace your current Quote Sub for this:

```
Sub Quote()

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Company() As String ' Converted the company variable to an array
    Dim InfoA As String
    Dim Finalrow As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    Set Source = Worksheets("Data")
    Set Target = Worksheets("Quotation ENG")
    Company = Split(Worksheets("Manager").Range("E5").Value, ",") 'Where one dropdown list is located.
    InfoA = Worksheets("Manager").Range("E7").Value 'Where one dropdown list is located.

    ' Added the source sheet and removed the select as it slows down your code
    Finalrow = Source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each company contained in the array
    For counter = 0 To UBound(Company)
        ' Loop through each data row
        For I = 2 To Finalrow
            ' Added Company(counter) so you can access each array element and wrapped it with trim to delete extra spaces
            If Source.Cells(I, 1) = Trim(Company(counter)) And Source.Cells(I, 2) = InfoA Then
                Source.Range(Source.Cells(I, 16), Source.Cells(I, 23)).Copy Target.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8)
            End If
        Next I
    Next counter


    ' Activate worksheet
    Target.Activate
    ' Refer to the object full path
    Target.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I just ran some tests and it works like a charm, thanks a lot. I also thank you for the comments in the code, they are helpful to me. It seems I have to study the split and the U bound functions, first time I hear about them.